# Mavericks issue: CAKeyframeAnimation on window does not animate

Tags: objective-c, animation, nswindow, osx-mavericks, caanimation

I am working on adapting my app to Mavericks since I have been developing it for 10.8. So far I have found various issues which I can't seem to be able to solve. One of them has to do with NSPopover-like animations.

I have a window which I animate in this way:

```
_zoomWindow.alphaValue = 0;
[_zoomWindow orderFront: self];

// Configure bouncing animation
CAKeyframeAnimation* frameAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
[frameAnim setTimingFunction: [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[frameAnim setValues: @[[NSValue valueWithRect: startFrame], [NSValue valueWithRect: overshootFrame], [NSValue valueWithRect: endFrame]]];
[frameAnim setDuration: duration];
[frameAnim setDelegate: self];

[_zoomWindow setAnimations: @{@"frame": frameAnim}];

// Configure alpha animation
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration: duration];
[[_zoomWindow animator] setAlphaValue: 1.0];
[[_zoomWindow animator] setFrame: endFrame display: YES];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

This works beautifully on 10.8! But it just doesn't do anything on 10.9. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The result was that it didn't show anything while suposedly animating, so at first I thought it wasn't animating at all. As it turns out, the problem was in another part of my code completely: the window that I was animating had the content view subclassed by me, and that view was doing some custom drawing. The real problem was that the view wasn't drawing anything on 10.9, even though it was drawing on 10.8... Once I fixed the drawing issue, the animation worked perfectly.